# Redirect example.com/abc to example.com/dir?q=abc without changing URL

Tags: .htaccess

I am creating a shortening URL site and I would like to treat example.com/abc123 as example.com/short?q=abc123 without changing the URL. I would like to do this in an .htaccess file but I don't know how and I don't know if anyone has ever done that. Does anyone know how? I'm sorry, I'm new to StackOverflow (sort of).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this rule in your root, i am assuming your original url is working and you have to rewrite it to `short?q=` although in your question you put the `dir?q=abc`.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)$ short?q=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Yeah, I know. I was shortening it in the title so it's not so long, gonna test it out now, thanks.

Comment: It ... worked! Thanks so much! I've marked this question as answered.